# multiple rows for row in pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

For a column in a pandas DataFrame with several rows I want to create a new column that has a specified number of rows that form sub-levels of the rows of the previous column. I'm trying this in order to create a large data matrix containing ranges of values as an input for a model later on.

As an example I have a small DataFrame as follows:

```
df:
    A
1   1
2   2
3   3
.   ..
```

To this DataFrame I would like to add 3 rows per row in the 'A' column of the DataFrame, forming a new column named 'B'. The result should be something like this:

```
df:
    A   B
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   1   3
4   2   1
5   2   2
6   2   3
7   3   1
8   3   2
9   3   3
.   ..  ..
```

I have tried various things of which a list comprehension combined with an `if` statement and using something to iterate over the rows in the DataFrame like `iterrows()` and subsequently 'append' the new rows seems most logic to me, however I cannot get it done. Especially the duplication of the 'A' column's rows.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Any suggestion is appreciated, many thanks in advance

Comment: What must be the output if the number of repeats were `4` instead?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.repeat(df['A'].values, 3), 
                   'B':np.tile(df['A'].values, 3)})
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  3
3  2  1
4  2  2
5  2  3
6  3  1
7  3  2
8  3  3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [28]: pd.DataFrame({'A':np.repeat(df.A.values, 3), 'B':np.tile(df.A.values,3)})
Out[28]:
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  3
3  2  1
4  2  2
5  2  3
6  3  1
7  3  2
8  3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another NumPy way with `np.repeat` to create one column and then re-using it for the another -

```
In [282]: df.A
Out[282]: 
1    4
2    9
3    5
Name: A, dtype: int64

In [288]: r = np.repeat(df.A.values[:,None],3,axis=1)

In [289]: pd.DataFrame(np.c_[r.ravel(), r.T.ravel()], columns=[['A','B']])
Out[289]: 
   A  B
0  4  4
1  4  9
2  4  5
3  9  4
4  9  9
5  9  5
6  5  4
7  5  9
8  5  5
```